# ANT Script Build Messages into a log4j configured log file

Tags: ant, log4j

I am developing a java project using Eclipse as IDE and ant as the build tool. For logging I am making use of log4j library. I am able to get the log messages in a log file for my whole application using log4j configuration.
But when I build project using ANT, the ANT build messages are still posted to console.I want to make sure that when I build the project, the build messages that ANT generates, like build failure/success, should also be posted to that sames logger file using log4j.

Please help me in this if anyone has got an idea. Thanks

Comment: Check this documentation: http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html you'll have their the explanation how to setup log4j logging with ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the logging log4j, you can use this when you run Ant:

```
$ ant -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener
```

The configuration of log4j is then up to you. See the information on [Listeners](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) in the Ant manual.

Comment: was looking for a detailed answer. Anyways I got it working...thanks for your time :-)